# extjs 4 portal example

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, portal

I would like to say that Im struggling with understanding the portal demo in ExtJS 4. Can someone please just provide me a generic example of a container and how to add a portlet item. The docs provided with the download do not have the word portal or portlet when I do the search. When I look at the source of the example there are classes files and extra CSS files too. Are those needed? I have searched all over the web and only seem to find other people asking the same question. Any help or even a link to a demo for extjs 4 would be greatly appreciated. Maybe my googlefoo is lacking?

When I use the demo and start modifying the border layout I run into all sorts of issues. The center region cannot contain a tab panel, I use accordion layouts for my east, west, and north regions. There seems to be an issue with the West region and having an accordion layout because it does not display properly ie. the accordion is like half open and any images inside do not display unless you collapse and then re-open. Would someone be able to provide me with an example that just shows how to make a basic portal without any added functionality? Below is the code I was using that was not working properly but displays and works fine (except for the portal part) when using just a viewport.

Here is some example code

```
Ext.define('Ext.app.Portal', {

    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    uses: ['Ext.app.PortalPanel'],

    initComponent: function(){
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
            id: 'main-viewport',
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: '0 5 5 5'
            },
            items: [{
                title: 'My Notifications',
                id: 'My-Notifications-Panel',
                region: 'north',
                height: 300,
                split: true,
                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: true,
                margins: '0 0 0 0',
                layout: 'accordion',
                items: [
                {
                    title: 'Alerts'
                },{
                    title: 'Communications'
                }
                ]
            },{
                title: 'My Support',
                id: 'My-Support-Panel',
                region: 'east',
                width: 140,
                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: true,
                margins: '0 0 0 0',
                layout: 'column',
                autoScroll: true,
                defaults: {
                    margins: '10 5 0 0',
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height: 100,
                    width: '100%',
                    headerPosition: 'bottom',
                    border: false,
                    cls: 'myicon',
                    bodyStyle: 'background-image: url(images/icon.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;'
                },
                items:[
                    {
                        title: 'Customer Services'
                    },{
                        title: 'Technical Support',
                        listeners: {
                            afterrender: function(c){
                                c.el.on('click', function(){
                                    CreateChatSession();
                                    Ext.getCmp('My-Support-Chat-Panel').update('<iframe width="100%" height="700" src="/pub/" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'west',
                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: true,
                title: 'My Apps',
                width: 275,
                layout:'accordion',
                split: true,
                margins: '0 0 0 0',
                defaults: {
                    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',
                    layout: 'column'
                },
                items: [{
                    title: 'Internal Apps',
                    defaults: {
                        padding: '5 5 5 5',
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        height: 100,
                        width: 80,
                        headerPosition: 'bottom',
                        border: false,
                        cls: 'myicon',
                        bodyStyle: 'background-image: url(images/icon.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;'
                    },
                    items: []
                },{
                    title: 'Favorites',
                    defaults: {
                        padding: '5 5 5 5',
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        height: 100,
                        width: 80,
                        headerPosition: 'bottom',
                        border: false,
                        cls: 'myicon',
                        bodyStyle: 'background-image: url(images/icon.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;'
                    },
                    items: []
                },{
                    title: 'Reporting',
                    defaults: {
                        padding: '5 5 5 5',
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        height: 100,
                        width: 80,
                        headerPosition: 'bottom',
                        border: false,
                        cls: 'myicon',
                        bodyStyle: 'background-image: url(images/icon.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;'
                    },
                    items: []
                }]
            },
                Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                    region: 'center',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    items: [{
                        id: 'Workspace-1',
                        title: 'Workspace 1',
                        layout: 'fit',
                        items: [{
                            id: 'app-portal',
                            xtype: 'portalpanel',
                            region: 'center',
                            items: [{
                                id: 'col-1',
                                items: [{
                                    id: 'portlet-2',
                                    title: 'Portlet 2',
                                    listeners: {
                                        'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                                    }
                                }]
                            },{
                                id: 'col-2',
                                items: [{
                                    id: 'portlet-3',
                                    title: 'Portlet 3',
                                    listeners: {
                                        'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                                    }
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                })
            ]
        }));
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: The source in that example will show you exactly how they accomplished what they did. Perhaps if you could make your question a bit more specific someone out there could help a bit more.

Comment: I have edited my question and added sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'ss the portal example with tabs in center region

Hope this will help you.

```
Ext.define('Ext.app.Portal', {

    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    getTools: function() {
        return [{
            xtype: 'tool',
            type: 'gear',
            handler: function(e, target, panelHeader, tool) {
                var portlet = panelHeader.ownerCt,
                    el = portlet.getEl();

                el.mask('Working...');
                Ext.defer(el.unmask, 2000, el);
            } //eo handler function
        }]; //eo return
    }, //eo get tools

    initComponent: function() {

        var content = '<div class="portlet-content">' + Ext.example.shortBogusMarkup + '</div>';

        Ext.apply(this, {
            id: 'app-viewport',
            layout: {
                type: 'border',
                padding: '0 5 5 5'
            }, //eo layout
            items: [{ //header : item 1 of app-viewport
                    id: 'app-header',
                    xtype: 'box',
                    region: 'north',
                    height: 50,
                    html: 'myPortal'
                },
                { //container : item 2 of app-viewport
                    xtype: 'container',
                    region: 'center',
                    layout: 'border',
                    items: [{ //options: item 1 of container
                            id: 'app-options',
                            title: 'Options',
                            region: 'west',
                            animCollapse: true,
                            width: 200,
                            minWidth: 150,
                            maxWidth: 400,
                            split: true,
                            collapsible: true,
                            layout: 'accordion',
                            layoutConfig: {
                                animate: true
                            },
                            items: [{ //item 1 of app-options

                                    title: 'title',
                                    autoScroll: true,
                                    border: false,
                                    iconCls: 'nav',
                                    items: [{
                                        xtype: 'treepanel',
                                        useArrows: true,
                                        autoScroll: true,
                                        animate: true,
                                        enableDD: true,
                                        containerScroll: true,
                                        border: false,
                                        region: 'west',
                                        split: true,

                                        listeners: {
                                            click: function(n) {
                                                Ext.Msg.alert('Navigation Tree Click', 'You clicked: "' + n.attributes.text + '"');
                                            }
                                        }
                                        /*Dashboard
                                        MultiServices
                                        Reporting
                                        Global Options
                                        */
                                    }]

                                },
                                { //settings : item 2 of app-options
                                    title: 'Settings',
                                    html: '<div class="portlet-content">' + 'details ??' + '</div>',
                                    border: false,
                                    autoScroll: true,
                                    iconCls: 'settings'
                                }
                            ] //eo items options
                        },
                        { //item 2 of container
                            id: 'tabpanel1', // id: 'app-portal',  ???
                            xtype: 'tabpanel',
                            activeTab: 0,
                            region: 'center',
                            items: [{
                                title: 'tab1',
                                layout: 'column', //
                                closable: true,
                                items: [{
                                    id: 'col-1',
                                    columnWidth: 0.5,
                                    flex: 1,
                                    items: [{
                                        id: 'portlet-1',
                                        title: 'Grid Portlet',
                                        tools: this.getTools(),
                                        items: new Ext.app.GridPortlet(),
                                        listeners: {
                                            'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        id: 'portlet-2',
                                        title: 'Portlet 2',
                                        tools: this.getTools(),
                                        html: content,
                                        listeners: {
                                            'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                                        }
                                    }] //eo col-1
                                }, {
                                    id: 'col-2',
                                    columnWidth: 0.5,
                                    flex: 1,
                                    items: [{
                                        id: 'portlet-3',
                                        title: 'Portlet 3',
                                        tools: this.getTools(),
                                        html: '<div class="portlet-content">' + Ext.example.bogusMarkup + '</div>',
                                        listeners: {
                                            'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                                        }
                                    }] //eo col-2
                                }, {
                                    id: 'col-3',
                                    columnWidth: 0.5,
                                    flex: 1,
                                    margins: '0 26 0 0',
                                    items: [{
                                        id: 'portlet-4',
                                        title: 'Chart Portlet',
                                        tools: this.getTools(),
                                        items: new Ext.app.ChartPortlet(),
                                        listeners: {
                                            'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                                        }
                                    }] //eo col-3
                                }] //eo tab1
                            }, {
                                title: 'tab2',
                                closable: true
                            }] //eo items tabpanel
                        }
                    ] //eo ietms container

                }
            ] //eo viewport
        }); //eo apply

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }, //eo initcomponent

    onPortletClose: function(portlet) {
        this.showMsg('"' + portlet.title + '" was removed');
    },

    showMsg: function(msg) {
        var el = Ext.get('app-msg'),
            msgId = Ext.id();

        this.msgId = msgId;
        el.update(msg).show();

        Ext.defer(this.clearMsg, 3000, this, [msgId]);
    },

    clearMsg: function(msgId) {
        if (msgId === this.msgId) {
            Ext.get('app-msg').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Or u can try [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/layout/complex.html) I think it suits better ur needs ,let me know.

Comment: For some reason when this one renders all of the panels are not draggable and there are no tabs. was this working for you?

Comment: yes it works for me, but ur right not draggable, i havent resolved that issue yet.

Comment: if u really need the tabs and cant resolve the problem in my exxample,try looking in the sencha examples,im sure i saw a similar example to the portal but with tabs,but cant recall its name

Comment: I have been working on it for 2 weeks. I have exhausted myself. I usually try not to ask too much on here unless I just cant seem to figure something out

Comment: i understand this,ive been in the same situation (and maybe still), just started extjs4 fw months ago

Comment: try [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/layout/complex.html) i think it suits better ur needs ,let me know

Comment: ohh that is sexy. I think I will play with that for a bit. Thank you. I appreciate all the assistance

Comment: its my pleasure..if it helps u, u can close this post..good luck

Comment: Hey astrocybernaute, I have a similar requirement where I have to use the existing portal example, and have tabs in the center which in turn have portals and portlets in them. Also, I have to use the accordion as well on the left. So I just replaced my portal.js file with your code to fit in.. But I am getting some error which says this : `TypeError: h is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...f(!hasXml){xml=Ext.DomQuery.isXml(ci);hasXml=true}if(!xml){if(useGetStyle){a=Ext...`
Is it possible to tell me if we need to define the dependency for the `tabpanel` at the start or something? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind I solved it, but the problem is I do not see the Tabs on the Tab Bar.. How are we supposed to show the tabs? Is it a bug or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

----------- Just for anyone who reads this Portal Layout IS NOT part of the official framework and is a 3rd party extension bundled with the library, which is why it is not in the docs.